# Cron job to just open a webpage

Tags: cron

i have two servers, one is a windows server that doesnt have scheduled tasks, and i have a cpanel server that has cron jobs. i am trying to make a cron job to open a webpage on the windwos server. on the webpage it is just a simple code that looks into a data base and generates an email written in asp. the code works fine.

i have the cronjob currently as

```
wget http://www.website.com/6amcronjob.asp
```

i have also tried this that i found in another persons question

```
* * * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://www.website.com/6amcronjob.asp
```

the second one just gives me an error. the first one is accepted, but it is not actually opening the page. please assist.

All godaddy

Answer (score 0):

try using lynx instead of wget

lynx -dump http://www.website

lynx will not create temporary files either.  Also your seocnd example should have url than > /dev/null